# Unable to change font awesome icon color when checked - Check box

Tags: css, checkbox, font-awesome

the first one works but I am unable to change the color of the second (.fa ). I am able to change the font color while not active.

```css
#pgggo-sort-filter ul li label input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .icon-box{
  background: green;
  /* padding: 10px; */
}

#pgggo-sort-filter ul li label input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .fa{
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div id="pgggo-sort-filter" class="pgggo-sort-filter">
  <ul>
    <li>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="">
          <div class="icon-box">
            <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-down" area-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
        </label>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="">
          <div class="icon-box">
            <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-up" area-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
        </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <a class="button primary" href="#">Sort
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This one is fine...

The neighbor `~` of the checkbox can only be the element with the `icon-box` class and not its child with class  `fa`

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .icon-box{
  background: green;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .icon-box .fa {
  color: yellow;
}
```

Proof:

```css
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .icon-box{
  background: green;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .icon-box .fa {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div id="pgggo-sort-filter" class="pgggo-sort-filter">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="">
        <div class="icon-box">
          <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-down" area-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="">
        <div class="icon-box">
          <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-up" area-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
      </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <a class="button primary" href="#">Sort </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Its the same thing as putting the font color in the parent element.

Comment: @drtechno it's better to be precise, especially in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want a yellow arrow, when the checkbox is only selected, only one css declaration is needed:

```css
#pgggo-sort-filter ul li label input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .icon-box{
  background: green;
  /* padding: 10px; */
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Font Awesome Icons</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

</head>
<body style="font-size:24px;">
 <div id="pgggo-sort-filter" class="pgggo-sort-filter">
              <ul>
                <li>
                   <label>
                     <input type="checkbox" name="">
                     <div class="icon-box">
                       <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-down" area-hidden="true"></i>
                     </div>
                   </label>
                   <label>
                     <input type="checkbox" name="">
                     <div class="icon-box">
                       <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-up" area-hidden="true"></i>
                     </div>
                   </label>
                </li>
              </ul>
             
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which one do you want change font color? the one that gets highlighted green? Because that what I wrote as an answer.

Comment: It should always because font color fallows the element. If this doesn't work, then the browser you are testing with is non-standard.

Comment: Mine is latest chrome. For some reason, it works in the code snippet

Comment: I think there something else going on for it not to work. This was hardwired into back 30+ years ago. Sometimes Calling style sheets in the wrong order can do things, but I try to do custom css inline (in the <style> tag instead of external sheets) because external style sheets are cached and can be problem when trying to debug things.

Comment: You didn't not explain anything (+ you reproducing the use of double quote for nothing)